# Fetching wordpress page featured image to the header.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress-driven site with the template having a jcycle slider in the frontpage. I wish to use a static banner in all the pages except for the homepage. I found a function in my header.php file as below:

```
<?php   else : // NOT front page ?>`
    <div id="page-content-title">
        <div id="page-content-header" class="container_24">
            <div id="page-title">
```

How can I display an image here from PAGE FEATURED IMAGE?

Answer (score 0):

Well to start you probably want a specific size for that image. Use [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in your functions.php file to do that. Then use [wp_image_attachment_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).

To get that image on the page, do something like this:

```
<?php
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'slider-size' );
    echo ('<img src="' . $thumbnail[0] . '">');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

below script will help you to get featured image if post have ...

```
query_posts(); 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
$featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
echo $featuredImage; 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's a cleaner way to do this by passing a parameter into the `post_thumbnail` callback. Here's what I came up with. hope this helps. This only prints the featured image if it exists and wraps your header image in a div so you can control position in the DOM.

```
<?php // Loop used to show post-thumbnail as #header-image if it exists 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div id="header-image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
            </div>

            <?php } else { ?>

            <?php }?>
```